# Azure Database Migration Service security questions

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, migration, azure-sql-database

Two questions I am not in a position to confirm via deploying to an Azure resource group (due to my account limitations). So far, I have not found resources that answers my questions.

**1. AD Users and Groups**

Can Active Directory (AD) Users and AD Groups SQL Server Logins or Database users be migrated from On premise SQL databases to Azure SQL?

The environment I will be working on has the on premise AD synced to Azure Active Directory (AAD).

So far, I have only seen that SQL Logins can be migrated.

**2. Authentication**

I know that SQL Login and Windows Authentication login are options to connect to the Source database. Are both of these option also available in the destination Azure SQL database?

So far I have only seen SQL Login as an option for connection to the destination database (see below screenshot). This might be because there are no AAD accounts associated with the blank Azure SQL target database I am trying to connect to. The Server Admin is set for the target database.

[image]

Comment: 1. No. Though it does support [Azure Active Directory Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-overview). 2. See 1.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately you can't migrate the Active Directory (AD) Users and AD Groups to Azure SQL Database. Yes, you move SQL logins from the SQL Server source to Azure SQL Database by using Database Migration Service in offline mode.

You can also migrate Windows users and groups using T-SQL DDL syntax with the help of this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/migrate-sql-server-users-to-instance-transact-sql-tsql-tutorial).

You can use Azure AD authentication to connect with Azure SQL Database. **It is an alternative to SQL Logins Authentication.** Please refer [Azure Active Directory authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-overview) for more details.

**You can simply use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to connect with Azure SQL Database using Azure AD credentials.** Install the SSMS on your local windows machine and login with AAD credentials as shown in image below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, for clarifying that cannot migrate the AD entities, Utkarsh.

Regarding Connection via AAD auth to Azure SQL Database. Are you saying that this exists in DMS UI - as distinct from general connection option (such as from a client app)? 
I only see SQL Authentication in the dropdown as an option.

Comment: To make it clearer, I have added a screenshot of the DMS wizard to my original post. This shows the UI I see for configuring the Target. I am trying to clarify if for Azure SQL database (not Azure MI database) there are circumstances that AAD login option might appear in the dropdown.

Comment: You can use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to connect with Azure SQL Database using Azure AD credentials. I have updated my answer with required information.